# How do I exit the Windows Insider Program and update my Windows 10 to Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-insider

I purchased a new laptop a few months back, and I decided to enroll for Windows 11 Insider Program a few months back. Now when Windows 11 has been officially released, I attempted to unenroll the Insider Program and downgrade it to Windows 10 and update it again to official Windows 11 and not to Insider but I am not able to unenroll from Windows Insider. Please help me and do tell me if my question is inaccurate or uncertain.

Screenshot of Windows update page
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience caused, I have made the changes to make it more understandable.

Comment: If you are unable to unenroll from the Insider Preview builds it means you likely have installed a Insider Preview Developer channel build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 11, Start, Settings, Windows Update, Right side, Windows Insider Program, Stop getting Preview Builds.

Now you need to wait.

It says:  (taken from my Windows 11 Preview machine)

> Unenroll this device when the next version of Windows Releases.

How far back your system can go will depend on what Windows.old you have.

If also says:

> Unenroll this device immediately.  You will need to do a clean install
> of the latest release of Windows 10.

Those are your two choices. With the first choice, depending on your Windows.old file, you may have to reinstall Windows 10 in any event.